# Linear regression implementation in Octave

Tags: machine-learning, octave, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I recently tried implementing linear regression in octave and couldn't get past the online judge. Here's the code

```
function [theta, J_history] = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)

m = length(y); % number of training examples
J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1);

for iter = 1:num_iters
    for i = 1:m
      temp1 = theta(1)-(alpha/m)*(X(i,:)*theta-y(i,:));
      temp2 = theta(2)-(alpha/m)*(X(i,:)*theta-y(i,:))*X(i,2);
      theta = [temp1;temp2];
    endfor

    J_history(iter) = computeCost(X, y, theta);

end

end
```

I am aware of the vectorized implementation but just wanted to try the iterative method. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the inner `for` loop. Instead you can use the `sum` function.

In code:

```
for iter = 1:num_iters

    j= 1:m;

    temp1 = sum((theta(1) + theta(2) .* X(j,2)) - y(j)); 
    temp2 = sum(((theta(1) + theta(2) .* X(j,2)) - y(j)) .* X(j,2));

    theta(1) = theta(1) - (alpha/m) * (temp1 );
    theta(2) = theta(2) - (alpha/m) * (temp2 );

    J_history(iter) = computeCost(X, y, theta);

end
```

It'd be a good exercise to implement the vectorized solution too and then compare both of them to see how in practice the efficiency of the the vectorization.

Comment: I understand it can be done that way. Could you please point out to me what is the error in my approach?